# java zipentry getsize returns -1

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream

Java zipEntry.getSize() returns the size of the actual file and some times it returns -1 (though the file size is greater than 0).

Java API document says "Returns the uncompressed size of the entry data, or -1 if not known."

Not sure on what situation it will return -1 i.e. on what situation it will be unknown?

Comment: FWIW if you call `getSize` after reading the stream for that ZipEntry, then it will return the right size. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll get a return of -1 if that is what is in the ZipFile entry table. This is quite simply just an aspect of the definition of the zip file format.

Comment: I get -1 even after writing the size to the zip table with the size function.

Answer (score 10):

Surprisely using ZipFile instead of ZipInputStream for getting the entries
makes getSize and getCompressedSize to return the right values.

```
     ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("myFile.zip"); 
     java.util.Enumeration zipEnum = zipfile.entries();
     while (zipEnum.hasMoreElements ()) 
     { 
        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipEnum.nextElement(); 
        if (! entry.isDirectory ())
        {
            // entry.getName()
            // entry.getSize ()
            // entry.getCompressedSize ()
         }
     }
```

trick found at http://vimalathithen.blogspot.de/2006/06/using-zipentrygetsize.html

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the correct size of zipEntry:

```
ZipInputStream( BufferedInputStream( cr.openInputStream(zipUri) ) ).use { srcZipStream ->
        var zipEntry: ZipEntry?
        while (srcZipStream.nextEntry.also { zipEntry = it} != null) {
            srcZipStream.closeEntry()
            allZipEntryList.add(zipEntry!!.name)
            Log.e("wkExtract",zipEntry!!.name+" size= "+zipEntry!!.size+" compressed size= "+zipEntry!!.compressedSize)
        }
}
```